# Transparent Label in Menu area with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, menu, label, transparent

I've read many articles on how to create transparent labels but it seems to me that my particular case is not covered. Very simply I have a label placed in the upper right part of the form, which in fact is part of the menu strip. The label displays some info to the user but I wish it were transparent. Ive tried various methods including

```
lblAct.Parent = mnuMain '(or Me)
lblAct.BackColor = Color.Transparent
lblAct.BringToFront()
```

but cant get it to work. Anyone have suggestions on how I can make that lable in that position transparent?

Thanks

AGP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can't make this work.  It's a Windows restriction, transparency effects are relative to the top-level window, stacking effects do not work.  You'll see the form as the background, not the menu strip.  Hacking a label that asks the menustrip to render itself to create the background is technically possible.  But Windows won't generate a paint message when the strip repaints itself.  Which will be starkly visible when the user resizes the form for example.