# Label background wont go transparent

Tags: vb.net

[image]

I got this problem were few of my labels wont go transparent but the labels on the right goes transparent I use this codes to make the labels transparent

```
        Sc.Parent = PictureBox1
        Sc.BackColor = Color.Transparent
        Sc.BringToFront()
        Sc.Location = New Point(150, 24)
```

But on the left side of the image you will see the labels wont go transparent I want the text to cover the arrows but now with a box. I made the moving arrow transparent too it works fine but dont really now what is the problem of the labels here is a sample of the code for the arrows

```
With ArrowRight
.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
End With

With RArrowRight
    .Parent = PictureBox2
    .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
    .BackColor = Color.Transparent
End With
```

Comment: Controls in WinForms are only transparent with respect to their container.  The transparency won't work when the controls overlap each other.

Comment: so theres really no hope? =(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548599/transparent-label-in-menu-area-with-vb-net?rq=1

Comment: "no hope?"...depends.  You can make the control non-rectangular by building a GraphicsPath() representing the area you want to keep and then passing that to a new Region().  Set the Region() property of your control to that and it will overlap in a nice fashion.  This can be done with text as well.  It's not fool-proof, or particularly easy if your shape isn't trivial.

Comment: I dont quite get it dont know what the use of graphics path()

Comment: Start small.  Create a GraphicsPath() and add an Ellipse to it.  Create a Region() from that and assign it some control to see how it effects it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overlapping component are a headache.
Why don't you just use the .***Visible*** property. In this case, the image that need to be hidden, goes invisible and the one to appear goes ***Visible***, without the need to use the .BringToFront;

```
    Sc.Parent = PictureBox1
    Sc.Visible = True 
    Sc.Location = New Point(150, 24)
```

And on hiding,

```
   Sc.Visible = False
   MyNextImage.Visible = True
```